# W/L effect on mosfet mobility

Tags: mosfet

I want to know how does the change in the physical MOSFET parameters affect the mobility and the Cox. Suppose i have W/L = 1u/130n and i changed it to 2u/260n my Kn' is now bigger why is that? I mean the ratio is the same. I want to know how does Kn' depend on W/L thanks.

it's a simulation using cadence virtuoso spectre and the mosfet is from the tsmc13rf library its the nmos1v.

i am sweeping V1 from 0 to 2 volts and calculating kn from the output graph of Id vs V1

[Schematic http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/12ce/agohod3u5d69hrvfg.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/12ce/agohod3u5d69hrvfg.jpg)

Comment: Could you please provide more framework to your question: is this simulation or experimental results? For simulation explain what transistor model did you use; for experiment please provide a bit more details about transistor's structure (topology, halo implant, strained silicon, etc.). Currently there can be no answer to your question, because there are too many unknown parameters.

Comment: We can assume that \$V_{in}>V_T\$, right? I think that the only information missing now is the graph itself, and a bit of explanation about how did you estimate \$K_n\$ from the graph.

Comment: the simulation results give me lambda and all the other values of the current equations are things i have except the Kn' i take a point and calculate it. and Vin is of course > Vt

Answer (score 1):

The oxide capacitance is a function of the oxide thickness and its relative permittivity, and it is essentially independent of the W and L. Carrier mobility depends primarily on the concentration of dopants (in the bulk silicon) but in the presence of high electric fields the mobility can be limited by hot-carrier effects. If your transistors start to exhibit hot-carrier effects at 130n then this could explain why the K' is different for a gate length of 260n under the same voltage conditions.

Now, what makes you think your K' changed? Are you calculating it by hand or obtaining values from a simulation?

EDIT: The behavior of a real transistor is far more complex than the simple equations that use K', and your Spectre simulation is also using a far more complex model. If your observed K' is within 10% of the value you calculated I would say that's as close as you can expect.

Comment: i am using cadence and this it what i observed from my change in w/l ratio. i kept the ratio the same but found kn changing

Comment: Cadence is a company, not a tool or a simulator. **Exactly** how did you observe K' changing?

Comment: yeah i am sorry.. i am using virtuoso spectre